# Question in relating STLC and Free CCC

Tags: type-theory, lambda-calculus, ct.category-theory, typed-lambda-calculus

In Lambek's [Intro to Higher Order Cat Logic](https://books.google.ca/books?id=6PY_emBeGjUC&pg=PA41&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false), Chapter 1 Section 4 introduces the free construction (upon graph) [image]

My question is, if I want to have STLC + (fake/incomplete) boolean type, how do I have the corresponding category? One suggestion I was given is to generate upon two arrows from a vertex "1" to a vertex "2", but it seems to me that, this free construction will add a new terminal object into the resulting CCC and the vertex "1" doesn't necessary become the desired terminal object and thus I am still confused where do I have `tt, ff : 1 -> 2`

[3]: Thanks for Trebor's correction on the terminology, that shouldn't be a boolean type but a fake/incomplete boolean type

Comment: That's multiple questions. As for the first question, it is obviously meant that 1 is the terminal object. Or more directly, that the coproduct 1+1 (but not necessarily the other coproducts) exists.

Comment: @Trebor Thanks for quick feedback! Do you mind elaborate that? Because in my understanding, the free construction will have a new T(==1) added inside the resulting CCC, the old 1' from the graph doesn't seem to be related to the new T? Do you mean that they are iso?

Comment: @Trebor Also why is that a coproduct because I didn't meant to impose the if rules (the elimination for the vertex "2")? Do the universal property just also appear together at the end?

Comment: The book is already adding products. Why not do the same to coproducts?

Comment: @Trebor This is just my small example, I intend to just add 2 without universal property. I am more curious on the "reaction" of the free construction and if I cannot control what is added and what is not added then I will need to be extra cautious about this concept

Comment: No. 2 **is** the coproduct 1 + 1, and this is a fact no matter how you formulate it. Without the universal property, there would be no such thing as "2". The best you can do is to manually add everything so as to avoid the phrase "universal property", but I don't consider it any more illuminating. You *can* just add **one coproduct** which is 1+1, **without adding anything else**.

Comment: @Trebor Thanks for the correction. I will avoid using some confusing phrase "2 without universal property" haha.  So what you mean is that, if I generate free CCC with graph { "A" ---two arrows--> "B" }, the elimination rule for coproduct  "B" won't appear with "B" right? or do you mean the elimination rule for coproduct will appear together with "B"

Answer (score 2):

If you start out with a graph $1 \rightrightarrows 2$, then what you get is not the $2$ you'd expect. The result would be equivalent to (in the resulting logic):

```
postulate
  A B : Set
  f g : A -> B
```

So you equivalently added two types (two propositions, two sets, whatever), and that there are two functions. But you don't get the case distinction (a.k.a. if-then-else) for the Boolean type.

---

If you *do* want the if-then-else thing, you should not modify $\mathscr X$. Rather, you should modify the free generation process. In the book you first put in a 1, and then add products, and add all the arrows resulting from universal properties. So you just sneak in an extra object 2 when you put in the 1, and add all the arrows together with the universal properties.

Comment: Do I even have one element from the CCC unit to this A? i.e. , A closed element of A, and thus two closed element of B?

Comment: @EDJ No. There are no extra information. And this "no extra information" thing is the *whole point* of **freeness**.